# Last accessed, last changed

Tags: excel, vba

i want to build a tool which show me when i had my last acces or last change in differents path and folders. In generelly i think my tool should work. But i only want to get the last accesed and last changed file to fill in my Worksheet. I´m not that good in discribing so i hope my code give you better information

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim cb As Control
    Dim I As Integer
    For Each cb In ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes
'        If Left(cb.Name, 8) = "Checkbox" Then
        If cb = True Then
            str_mandant = Right(cb.Name, Len(cb.Name) - 3)
            str_sparkasse_pfad = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Mandantenliste").Range("Mandanten").Find(what:=str_mandant, lookat:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValue).Offset(0, 2).Value
            Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetFolder(str_sparkasse_pfad & "\Eingang\")
            With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Arbeitsvorrat")
                int_zeile = .Cells(2, 26).End(xlDown).Row
                For Each file In fso.Files
                    int_zeile = int_zeile + 1
                    .Cells(int_zeile, 2) = "Sparkasse"
                    .Cells(int_zeile, 10) = file.DateCreated
                    .Cells(int_zeile, 6) = file.DateLastAccessed
                    .Cells(int_zeile, 8) = file.DateLastModified
                Next
            End With
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

I hope you guys can help me. Thanks!

Comment: If you mean the "last accessed" date in the file system? That is *completely* unreliable and means nothing. You should under no circumstances build anything that uses this date.

Comment: Yeah i mean "last accessed". Can i ask u why i should not build anything using this date?

Comment: Because all kinds of things that are not under your control access files all the time. "Virus scanners" is the first thing that comes to mind, but there are others, full text indexers for example. The date means nothing. Ignore it.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve, is the real question here?

Comment: On UI I can select different Paths. Then the Code should show me which file i haven´t opened for the longest time

Comment: This is impossible with the information the file system can give you.

Comment: In other words, build a system that records when you last access a file.